# Port Sqlite application to a server/client application

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, sqlite

I have wrote an Application for a organisation and they had let the app run in their lan using Samba, it worked perfect. Now they want to work over the internet.
The Problem is that I have written this app with Sqlite, that means its currently working so:

They have a exe and the sqlite dll and the sqlite database on their samba server and they connected a network drive on their windows pc to run it. So that means every pc is writing over samba to the sqlite database.

I tried it over the internet, but like i thought sqlite is a local database and its very slow, even if the ping is under 50ms.

I could create a tcp server, that handles all and writes all to the sqlite database, but I have already written around 20.000 code lines for the project, so that would be not the best option for the lazy me. I have used only one sqlite class in my client for querieng, so I thought that it could work without much work, if i would replace the sqlite database adapter with the mysql database adapter, since sqlite has nearly the same syntax then mysql.

Or has anybody a better idea?

Comment: Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL? You might want to check with this "organization" for any details of existing client server setup and budget.

Comment: Budget isnt really relevant there, theyll buy a linux server

Comment: You are the best judge of your code. From what you said, yes it's a good idea to use MySql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqLite is not designed for concurrent transaction (it can be done, but that's another post). If it's going to available via the internet your best bet is to migrate the database to one of the free databases (mySql, Sql Server Express, Oracle Express...etc)

Comment: And I should use the client for connecting to the mysql database directly or isnt that secure, I used before RSA for transmitting AES key, is connecting to a mysql database also secure like that(there are also credit card datas on the server)?

Comment: Ok I found the answer myself, its possible even with the .net libary and the .net libary is written by mysql itself, not second handed like postgre sql, so ill use mysql.

Comment: It all depends on the nature of the information transmitted. If the data is sensitive, then you'll want to consider security around the data. This can be as simple as encryption  or you can add a web server and proxy information from the database through the web server and out to your application.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL configured with a self-signed SSL certificate may be a suitable candidate. 
Porting a SQL dump from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL is trivial in most cases.

Comment: Sounds not bad, but do you know a .NET Provider which supports such SSL connections?

Comment: IIRC Npgsql supports SSL. But I haven't used it, as I'm using Qt/C++ in a similar application.

Comment: here's an interesting blog post: [Using SSL Client Certificates with Npgsql](http://fxjr.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-ssl-client-certificates-with.html)